# CSS Transition from no background color to gradient

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is it possible to make a transition from a div without background to a div with gradient background?

```
div { background-color:none;}

div:hover {
background:#D74413; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#D74413), to(#8A2D0D)); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #D74413, #8A2D0D); background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D74413, #8A2D0D); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #D74413, #8A2D0D); background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #D74413, #8A2D0D);
}
```

Comment: I would use jQuery to do that.  CSS3 is not supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Animating gradients is not simple and involves playing with background-size and -position of the gradients. Shown here for example:

http://www.impressivewebs.com/animating-css3-gradients/

An easy workaround that works for me is to put the gradient on a child of the div and animate it's opacity like here:

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/rWpZN/

---

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="back"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS (for webkit, but would work for other modern browsers too if you add the variants)

```
#container { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500px; height: 500px;
  background: transparent;
}    

#back { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ccc, #999);     
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-out;
}    


#container:hover #back {
  opacity: 1;
}​
```

Comment: you're too fast, i was writing the same example as your fiddle ;-) oh, please add the full code in your answer, for future reference

Answer (score 1):

Use this site:

[Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: But my question is, how to animate from one to another background with css3 transition!! Many thanks for your reply! :)